# Columns width in DT::datatable with filters

Tags: css, r, dt

For the column width, when the filters are not present, we can see that the width is automatically fixed according to the length of the terms, as we can see below:

[image]

But the we add filters, the column width becomes equal for all.

[image]

I would like to know if it is possible to get the "auto width" feature even when the filters are present.